# vue test utils doesn't fire trigger

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I am trying to simulate a trigger event and test that it has actually fired, but I keep having an empty response.

this is the code:

```html
<v-btn small class="elevation-0" 
     @click="$emit('close')">
        cancel
</v-btn>
```

```js
it('Should emit close when the CANCEL button is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(TaskForm, {
      propsData: {
        teamMembers: project.teamMembers,
        task: new Task({ project, name: '' })
      }
    });

    wrapper.findComponent(VBtn).trigger('click');

    expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty('close');
  });
```

Ok I have found the solution: basically trigger cannot be called on a component, therefore I have opted for component.vm.$emit('click') that  does the job the right way

Comment: How many `<v-btn>` elements are in your component?

Comment: there are 3, but the cancel button is the first one ( also tried with findAllComponents.at(0) )

Comment: Do you think you could add details of the component you're testing?

Comment: Here there is the full component https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-sanderson-n0tmo?file=/src/App.vue without the vuex actions for brevity sake